# How to stop autoplay next video dailymotion?

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe, dailymotion-api

I have created a test page with two example:

1. Iframe embed HTML
2. JavaScript SDK

I have tried to set parameter "queue-autoplay-next" to false but not working and when first video finish automatically start the secondo one.

Documentation here: https://developer.dailymotion.com/player

**My Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>      
    <iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270" 
                src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x7024it?autoplay=true&ui-highlight=c90c0f&mute=0&queue-autoplay-next=false&sharing-enable=false&ui-logo=false&ui-start-screen-info=false&queue-enable=true" 
                allowfullscreen allow="autoplay">
    </iframe>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script src="https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js"></script>
    <script>
    var player = DM.player(document.getElementById("player"), {
        video: "x7024it",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        params: {
            autoplay: true,
            mute: false,
            "queue-autoplay-next": false,
            "ui-highlight": "c90c0f",
            "sharing-enable": false,
            "ui-logo": false,
            "ui-start-screen-info": false,
            "queue-enable": true
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with JSP.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your feedback, it's indeed a bug in the player. We will fix it asap.

Meanwhile you can use `"queue-autoplay-next": 0` as a workaround.

We apologize for the inconvenience.